# Django query - connect User Class with OnetoOnefield class for Telegram Bot

Tags: python, django, view, model, telegram

I am having an issue with querying an attribute from a custom class connected with the user class.

My Goal: I want to send messages on my website per mouseclick via telegram bot to my phone (messaging works) - For this I need the USER´S CHAT ID

As there are multiple users I stored the chat_id in a new model I created,  which is linked to User model with a onetoonefield:

```
User = get_user_model()

class TelegramProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default="",max_length=200,blank=True,unique=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="user_id")
    telegram_chat_id = models.CharField(max_length=40,default="",editable=True,blank=True,unique=True)
   
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

My Usermodel is the built in Model:

```
class User(auth.models.User, auth.models.PermissionsMixin):

def __str__(self):
    return f"@{self.username}"
```

So in my views.py file I have the function on which I grab the message (another model class called Recipe - I identify it by a primary key) and and the chat_id which belongs to a specific user:

```
  def bot(request,msg,chat_id,token=my_token):
        bot=telegram.Bot(token=token)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=msg)



  def home(request,pk):
      recipe = get_object_or_404(Recipe,pk=pk)
      user = request.user
      chat_id = User.objects.get(TelegramProfile.telegram_chat_id,user) #with this query I try to grab the chat_id of the logged in user
      ingredients = recipe.ingredients
      ingredients = ingredients.split("<p>")
      ingredients = "\n".join(ingredients)
      ingredients = strip_tags(ingredients)
      bot(request,ingredients,chat_id)
      return render(request,"recipes/send_recipe.html")
```

So my question is:

-How do I make the query for the chat_id so that:
the chat_id of the **specific logged** in User will be called so I can insert it in the bot function to send the message to this specific id?

I am still new in django so I am still learning the queries, thanks so much in advance!!!

Comment: what's your error exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Was able to solve it myself:

```
def send_recipe(request, pk):
  try:
    if request.method == "POST":
        data_option = str(request.POST[
                              "testselect"])  # testselect is the select form in recipe_detail.html with which I select 1 of the 2 options
        if data_option == "Ingredients":
            recipe = get_object_or_404(Recipe, pk=pk)
            recipe_name = recipe.name.upper()
            ingredients = recipe.ingredients
            ingredients = ingredients.split("<p>")
            ingredients = "\n".join(ingredients)
            ingredients = strip_tags(ingredients)
            message = f"{recipe_name}: \n {ingredients}"

            user = TelegramProfile.objects.get(
                user=request.user)  # use get instead of filter! filter returns the name but can t use it as object, with get I get the object and I can use the attributes on it!
            chat_id = user.telegram_chat_id
            bot(request, message, chat_id)
            return render(request, "recipes/send_recipe.html")
        elif data_option == "Ingredients & Description":
            recipe = get_object_or_404(Recipe, pk=pk)
            recipe_name = recipe.name.upper()  # recipe name
            ingredients = recipe.ingredients
            ingredients = ingredients.split("<p>")
            ingredients = "\n".join(ingredients)
            ingredients = strip_tags(
                ingredients)  # we grab recipes ingredients and mute them, split at p tag, then add a new line and join them then remove tags
            recipe_description = recipe.description
            recipe_description = recipe_description.split("<p>")
            recipe_description = "\n".join(recipe_description)
            recipe_description = strip_tags(recipe_description)
            message = f"{recipe_name}: \n {ingredients} \n \n {recipe_description}"

            user = TelegramProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            chat_id = user.telegram_chat_id
            bot(request, message, chat_id)
            return render(request, "recipes/send_recipe.html")
    else:
        return render(request, "recipes/create_telegram.html")
  except Exception:
    return render(request, "recipes/create_telegram.html")
```